# How to Create a nested index in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

A. How do I index `nested` and all of it's values?

B. How do I index `valuetwo`?

```
{
    id: 00000,
    attrs: {
        nested:{
            value: value1,
            valuetwo: value2,
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes, and the docs to my knowledge, aren't clear about indexing things that aren't nested.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You'd create them just as if you were creating an index on a top level field:

```
db.collection.createIndex({"attrs.nested.value": 1})
```

You do need to explicitly create indexes on each field.

Answer (score 15):

MongoDB automatically creates a multikey index if any indexed field is an array; you do not need to explicitly specify the multikey type.

This will work for both the scenario's

```
db.coll.createIndex( { "addr.pin": 1 } )
```

Scenario 1 nested OBJECTS

```
{
  userid: "1234",
  addr: {
    pin:"455522"
  }
},
{
  userid: "1234",
  addr: {
    pin:"777777"
  }
}
```

---

Scenario 2 nested Arrays

```
{
  userid: "1234",
  addr: [
    { pin:"455522" },
    { pin:"777777" },
  ]
}
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/

Answer (score 13):

**A.** to index all the properties in "nested" you will have to index them separately:

```
db.collection.createIndex({"attrs.nested.value": 1});
db.collection.createIndex({"attrs.nested.valuetwo": 1});
```

This can be done in one command with:

```
db.collection.createIndexes([{"attrs.nested.value": 1}, {"attrs.nested.valuetwo": 1}]);
```

**B.** to index just "valuetwo":

```
db.collection.createIndex({"attrs.nested.valuetwo": 1})
```

Use [createIndex](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db.collection.createIndex) over ensureIndex as ensureIndex is [Deprecated since version 3.0.0](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/#db.collection.ensureIndex)

Comment: The two sets of index creation commands you give in A are *not* equivalent. The first creates separate indexes on `value` and `valuetwo`. The second creates a single compound index on both of these values. This index can only be used for queries which specify a value for `value`. That is, it's not useful for queries on `valuetwo` alone.

Comment: There is a [createIndexes()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createIndexes/#dbcmd.createIndexes) command (plural) which can create multiple indexes in one command. (As @MichaelMior points out, your code creates one compound index, not two separate indexes.) I haven't tried it, but it looks like you would do- `db.collection.createIndexes([{"attrs.nested.value": 1}, {"attrs.nested.valuetwo": 1}]);`

Comment: @Kip Thanks for pointing out `createIndexes`. I edited the answer to use this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there may have been a new feature to address this since these answers have been written.

Mongodb has wildcard indexes that allow you to create an index for a field that contains varying keys.

From the documentation:

> If the field is a nested document or array, the wildcard index recurses into the document/array and indexes all scalar fields in the document/array.

So the index in the question would be constructed like this:

`db.collections.createIndex({ "attrs.nested.$**": 1 })`

You can read more about this [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndexes/#create-a-wildcard-index)!

The previous answers nearly gave me a heart attack.