# Using Mongodb _id field to query partially on one or more of the composite fields

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using _id field as a compound key for my document with 2 fields as below.

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-08-25T05:43:00.000-19:30"),
        "hostName" : "nj"
    }

}
```

What I noticed it I am able to only query if I use both the fields together in my query. If I use one of them, I do not get any documents returned.

```
db.getCollection('sales').find(
{
    "_id" : {
            "hostName" : "tryme"     
    }

}

db.getCollection('sales').find(
{
    "_id" : {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-08-25T05:43:00.000-19:30")   
    }

}
```

The above script does not return any documents.

Also, I am not able to use $gte/$lte operators on the date fields,

```
db.getCollection('sales').find(
{
    "_id" : {
        "timestamp" : {
            "$lte":ISODate("2016-08-25T04:51:00.000-19:30")
        },
        "hostName" : "tryme"     
    }

}

)
```

The above also does not return any docs.

The below queries works but I see as per explain() it uses a collection scan and index is not used.

```
db.getCollection('sales').find(
{
    "_id.timestamp" : ISODate("2016-08-25T04:51:00.000-19:30"),
    "_id.hostName" : "tryme"     
}

)

==

db.getCollection('sales').find(
{
    "_id.timestamp" : {
        "$gte": ISODate("2016-08-25T04:52:00.000-19:30")
    },
    "_id.hostName" : "tryme"     
}

)
```

Not sure If I have understood how the _id field works correctly.

Basically, I want to be able to use partial fields of the composite query and also use the date type field also for range queries like between/greaterthan/lesser than etc at the same time leveraging the index on the _id field.

Can someone please help me on this.

Thanks,

Sri

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation):

> MongoDB uses the dot notation to access the elements of an array and
>   to access the fields of an embedded document.

Your firsts attempts doesn't work because you are passing a nested object as query which matches for equality, use dot notation instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but using dot notion results in collection scan and not using index. I checked it with .explain() method in mongo shell.I want to use an index for this query.

Comment: @user6594900 false, you can create a nested index: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730136/how-to-create-a-nested-index-in-mongodb. If you have a compound index, you need to query for all of its components for it to work